# Can't get the Ember tutorial to work with handlebars

Tags: ember.js

So I'm trying to learn Ember, and as I was working through the [tutorial](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/) on their website, I got stuck where it says to add `<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todos">` just after the body tag and close it at the end. Here is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ember.js • TodoMVC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todos">

  <section id="todoapp">
    <header id="header">
      <h1>todos</h1>
      <input type="text" id="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" />
    </header>

      <section id="main">
        <ul id="todo-list">
          <li class="completed">
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            <label>Learn Ember.js</label><button class="destroy"></button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            <label>...</label><button class="destroy"></button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            <label>Profit!</label><button class="destroy"></button>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-all">
      </section>

      <footer id="footer">
        <span id="todo-count">
          <strong>2</strong> todos left</span>
        <ul id="filters">
          <li>
            <a href="all" class="selected">All</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="active">Active</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="completed">Completed</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <button id="clear-completed">
          Clear completed (1)
        </button>
      </footer>
  </section>

  <footer id="info">
    <p>Double-click to edit a todo</p>
  </footer>
  </script>
   <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>
  <script src="js/application.js"></script>
  <script src="js/router.js"></script>
  <script src="js/models/todo.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

which I copied directly from the webpage, except to change the handlebars file name to the one I have. I know those links are valid and all go through, I checked in Eclipse. When I omit the handlebars script tags, it works fine, it's only after I add those the problem arises. I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572712/using-handlebars-end-up-displaying-nothing?rq=1) but neither of the answers worked. The other javascript files needed for the tutorial are all verbatim from the webpage, so they should work as well.

One thing I have noticed: at certain times (which I can't seem to relate to anything I do) I get the following ouput from the JavaScript Language Service:

> Referenced file '~/Scripts/_references.js' not found.

I don't know exactly what that means, but it looks like it might be the source of the problem

EDIT:

Router:

```
Todos.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('todos', {path: '/'});
});
```

Application:

```
window.Todos = Ember.Application.create();
```

Todo:

```
Todos.Todo = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'), isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

Comment: would you mind sharing the application.js/router.js/todo.js as well.  You should include an application template as well (with an {{outlet}}) but let's look at the rest of the code.

Comment: And you can ignore the _reference.js thing, I'm going to assume you're in visual studio, it's not important.

Comment: I wrote it in MVS and eclipse, that error showed up in MVS.

Comment: @kingpin2k I tried adding a 
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  {{outlet}}
</script> but that didn't work

Comment: Are you getting the Ember debug info in the console?

Comment: @kingpin Nope, I don't have anything in the console. I didn't tell it to display anything there though

Comment: By default Ember spits out debug info in the beginning, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/

Comment: @king Yeah I don't get anything when I open index.html. I do see it when I opened the emberjs.jsbin.com link

Comment: @king i figured it out, my javascript blocker was doing funny things. I had told it to let it all run, but it wasn't working properly. THanks for all your help

Comment: Glad to hear it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, please check which version on handlebars you are using, handlebars 3.0 is not supported.

There is compatibility issues going on try this starter kit it may work 
https://github.com/emberjs/starter-kit/releases/tag/v1.1.2